# (React) Run method on props change, including initial props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'd like to run a function upon receiving props initially and upon any subsequent props changes.  Consequently, I was planning on checking props and running this function in both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`.  However, this seems redundant.  I've seen people also check props and run functions inside `render()`, but I was under the impression this was frowned upon.

What should be my solution here?

Comment: Did you try your first method? Adding it to both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` might seem a little redundant..but these are likely the two lifehooks that most closely resemble the behavior you're looking for, so use them.

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate/componentWillUpdate is called before every render cycle,

Comment: I don't think `componentWIllUpdate` is called before the initial render: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate

Comment: @ChristopherMesser Yes, that is what I'm currently doing.

Comment: It depends on the structure of your component and what the function is (e.g.: is your component stateful? Are you manipulating the DOM?) It would be helpful if you posted the code for your component and the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no substitute to catch both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` in a single callback. The best way to do this is to define a function and call it from both of these callbacks.

> I was planning on checking props and running this function

Is a very vague description of what you're trying to do. Just checking the props alone doesn't seem to be problematic if done inside the `render` function. But it would become a problem if this part is causing side effects which (can) in turn trigger a component re-render. If this is the case, I'd say "frowned upon" is putting it lightly. The problem with this is that your render function is adding side effects which are in turn triggering more re-renders and on it goes. It will instantly kill the performance of your app and could even make the whole thing grind to a halt.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with both React and Redux. Are you using a `mapStateToProps` function that you use with `connect`?

If so, a possible answer could be to dispatch this action (or run this function) in the `mapStateToProps` function, since this will be run both initially, and then every time you update the redux state. You'd have to make sure the action/function doesn't cause yet another state change though, so that you end up in a loop.

**Edit**: @DuncanThacker pointed out this might not be a good idea, because `mapStateToProps` may fire very often, resulting in  performance issues. Good point.

Comment: I don't recommend this. Doing stuff in mapStateToProps() is hazardous because it can fire very frequently and cause nasty performance issues.

Comment: @DuncanThacker Yeah, that seems like a reasonable concern. Will edit my answer. Thanks!